# MVC Controller Action should only handle certain parameter values, 404 otherwise

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC controller action with one parameter that should only be called with certain values for that parameter (null/empty and some specific strings), in other cases it should not be hit (404 mostly). I've tried using a RegexRouteConstraint like below. But that doesn't filter the specific strings.

```
var route = new Route("{soortAanbod}", new MvcRouteHandler())
{
    Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Homepage", action = "Index", soortAanbod = UrlParameter.Optional }),
    Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { soortAanbod = new RegexRouteConstraint("a|b|c|d|e") }),
    DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary { { "area", context.AreaName } }
};
context.Routes.Add("Homepage_soortAanbod", route);
```

The controller looks like this: `public ActionResult Index(string soortAanbod)`

I've also tried using an action filter but that messes up other other filters. How can I make this route only match on the specified values for soortAanbod?

Comment: if this is one specific action, you have the choice to handle it directly in your action by code

Comment: It's several actions using the same constraint. Code can be an option but it's rather un-MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1. Your RegEx does not contain [anchors](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) (`^` and `$`) to delimit the string you are attempting to match. So, it is matching any string that *contains* any of these letters.
2. Your URL will *always* match the default route, so even if your custom route doesn't match, you will still get to the page. The default route will match *any* URL that is 0, 1, 2, or 3 segments in length.

You can get around this by removing your custom route and using an `IgnoreRoute` (which behind the scenes uses a [`StopRoutingHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.stoproutinghandler(v=vs.110).aspx)) to prevent those specific URLs from matching.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.IgnoreRoute("Homepage/Index/{soortAanbod}", 
            new { soortAanbod = new NegativeRegexRouteConstraint(@"^a$|^b$|^c$|^d$|^e$") });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

There is a caveat, though. RegEx's are [not very good at doing *negative matches*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word#406408), so if you are not a RegEx guru the simplest solution is to build a `NegativeRegexRouteConstraint` to handle this scenario.

```
public class NegativeRegexRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly string _pattern;
    private readonly Regex _regex;

    public NegativeRegexRouteConstraint(string pattern)
    {
        _pattern = pattern;
        _regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (parameterName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parameterName");
        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

        object value;
        if (values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value) && value != null)
        {
            string valueString = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return !_regex.IsMatch(valueString);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It was the anchors. Silly bug. This website doesn't have the default route, so only the anchors was enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try attribute routing or maybe write your own attribute for action to check params or redirect somewhere.

```
public class SomeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var yourstring = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["string"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourstring))
        {
            if (yourstring is not ok) 
            filterContext.Result =
                new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary
                    {
                        {"controller", "SomeCtrl"},
                        {"action", "SomeAction"}
                    });
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    }
```

Comment: I tried something like this (with a NotFoundResult) but it messes up the filter pipeline that is already present.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom constraint and use attribute routing, use the custom constraint there and make the constraint constructor accepts the list of strings that you want to avoid

[Custom MVC Route Constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs)

[Custom Constraint with Attribute Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-2-attribute-routing-with-custom-constraints)